# Problem Too many re-renders.Try to render components in connection with a button and state hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to react and face following problem: 
I have two buttons and want to render two different components. Pressing one button should set a variable true via state hook and the first component should be shown, on the other side the variable for the other component should be set to false. With this logic I try to render either one or the other component.

With this setup I get following Error Message:

**Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.**

I guess the solution is simple but I cannot see the why this causes a problem.
Thx for any help!

Here a simplified version of the relevant code:

```
import { Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [showAggregated, setshowAggregated] = useState(true);
  const [showDetailed, setshowDetailed] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      Test
      <Button.Group>
        <Button
          size="mini"
          onClick={(() => setshowAggregated(true), setshowDetailed(false))}
        >
          Aggregated Visualization{" "}
        </Button>
        <Button.Or />
        <Button
          size="mini"
          onClick={(() => setshowDetailed(true), setshowAggregated(false))}
        >
          Detailed Visualization
        </Button>
      </Button.Group>
      {/* Second Part of Page if Aggregated Component */}
      {showAggregated && <div>Aggregated</div>}
      {/* Second Part of Page if Detailed Component */}
      {showDetailed && <div>Detailed</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onClick={(() => setshowDetailed(true), setshowAggregated(false))}
```

You are using [Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) above, which evaluates each of its operands.

In your case you have 2 operands: `() => setshowDetailed(true)` **and** `setshowAggregated(false)`, so basically what happens is that each time the component is rendered, the second operand (`setshowAggregated(false)`) is called, which re-render the component which eventually ends up in an infinite loop.

What you really wanna do is this (an event handler that calls both functions):

```
onClick={() => {
   setshowDetailed(true);
   setshowAggregated(false));
}}
```

Same thing for the second button.